# Skip Next Coordinate

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `foo` where `x`, `y` represents coordinates
How do I discard the immediate next coordinate while using `select`?

```
  x   |  y | value 
------+-----+-------
   32 | 10 |     7
   32 | 11 |     2
   32 | 15 |     2
   32 | 16 |     5
   32 | 21 |    25
   33 | 17 |    57
   33 | 21 |    83
   33 | 22 |    86
```

`Output`

```
  x   |  y | value 
------+-----+-------
   32 | 10 |     7
   32 | 15 |     2
   32 | 21 |    25
   33 | 17 |    57
   33 | 21 |    83
```

Here cordinates `(32,11)`, `(32,16)`, `(33,22)` were skipped since they have an immediate previous coordinate `(32,10) -> (32,11)`, `(32,15) -> (32,16)`, `(33,21) -> (33,22)`

Is this possible using a query? 
I am using Postgres

Comment: @Nick That was a typo

Comment: Just wanted to check - it makes a big difference as to whether the answers are correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select *
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by x, y) % 2 as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Edit : After recheck the question you can use `lag()` :

```
select t.x, t.y, t.value
from (select t.*, 
             y - lag(y) over (partition by x order by y) as prev_val
      from table t
     )  t
where (t.prev_val is null or t.prev_val > 1);
```

Comment: @Nick. . . Thank you. Event i add partition clause. Still `row_number()` will not work for. I have added other.

Comment: @Nick. . . If you look at the sample output last row is not matching with this. Hence, i suggested new one.

Comment: @nick. . . No, if you look again, you see only immediate rows should be skipped with difference `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(y) over (partition by x order by y) as prev_y
      from t
     ) t
where prev_y is null or prev_y = y - 1;
```

In Postgres, you can also phrase the `where` as:

```
where prev_y is distinct from y - 1
```